# Mutt attachments in cache

Tags: cache, mutt

I am planning to try out mutt (and if it feels "solid" enough, migrate from Thunderbird)
Do I need to use offlineimap or some other solution to save the attachment locally, or does the built-in caching function in mutt store messages and their attachments in cache. As in, when I access the account when I am offline, will the attachment be available in cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, by setting the 'set message_cachedir=/some/dir/' you specify the cache for full mail bodies including attachments. Whether it is available when you are offline depends on whether you downloaded/read the mail before.

Note however that mutt does not allow offline reading. This means that you will have to use some external tools like grep in /some/dir/ to search for a mail and then extract an attachment.

Also note that each mail is a separate file and usually an attachment will be in base64 format, so you will have to extract the attachment from the text file manually and 'base64 -d' to decode it.

The recommended way is to use offlineimap.

Comment: Yes, I switched to offlineimap for downloading mail. Works well at the moment.